# How do I help allies when they are stunned/asleep/paralyzed/etc?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

In previous Monster Hunter Titles, there was usually a "special attack" that was really just a kick. The main use for this was helping allies out when they become "stuck".

However, in World... I've yet to figure out how to easily and quickly help out my allies in the same way. with 100+ hours in I think I would've found it if it exists, but nope...

I can still sometimes hit them with my weapon, as the "friendly fire" still exists, but even that has been incredibly toned down compared to other entries as well, so it's not as reliable as I'd like.

How do I perform the kick "attack" on command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A small prefaction first: when a hunter is asleep or stunned, any hit will free them of that status; if a hunter is paralyzed, it takes a hit that sends the hunter flying, either horizontally or vertically. Since the kick doesn't send hunters flying unless when having the Felyne Kickboxer skill, it wasn't helpful against paralysis.

The special kick attack is gone from Monster Hunter World, and is now only part of the Greatsword's moveset. You can guard and press the Triangle/Y button to perform a kick.

Other than that, the same rules apply: in order to break an ally out of sleep and stun you only need to hit them with any weapon attack. If you want to save a hunter from paralysis, however, you'll need to use specific moves, such as:

- The Greatsword's rising slash
- The Hammer's charged uppercut
- The Gunlance's wyvern fire
- The Switch Axe's rising slash in axe mode
- Certain Bowgun ammo such as Wyvern Ammo, Sticky Ammo, and Cluster Ammo

I don't believe any weapon other than the ones mentioned can help a paralyzed ally with any move.

Comment: As a bow user I can say I've never been able to help with paralysis.

Comment: I never played bow much but doesn't the meele action help with paralyse?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer No.  The bow's melee is a really minor knockback.  I don't think it can even knock a hunting out of a hammer charge.  For sure it isn't enough to knock a hunter off its feet.

Comment: Gunlance Shelling does not help paralysis. It seems the only thing that works is wyvern fire, now.